# Plot binary data as a region instead of a stem plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have some data that only takes on {0,1} values. For example, as a stem plot:

[image]

Since values are binary, I wish to plot this as regions instead. For example:

[image]

How do I do this in Python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for the matplotlib function: `matshow`. Here's your example:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = [1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1]

plt.matshow([data],            # convert to a 1xN matrix
            cmap = "binary_r") # See mpl documentation for other colors
plt.yticks([])                 # Turn off the y-axis
plt.show()
```

[image: Here's the plot result]

Comment: Thank you! One question: how do I use another data set for the x data instead of the array location? My x data is 200 values from 0 to 1, but the current solution shows the x data as points 1 to 200, and not [0,1] as desired.

Comment: There is a somewhat hacky way of doing this where you just overwrite the x labels on the plot:
`plt.xticks(np.arange(len(x_data)),labels=["{:.2f}".format(x) for x in x_data])`
you can change the `.2f` to whatever accuracy you need

Answer (score 1):

Here are two alternative ways. The first creates bar plots. The second uses `pcolormesh`.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap
import numpy as np

data = np.random.randint(0, 2, 10)
fig, axs = plt.subplots(ncols=3, figsize=(12, 2))
axs[0].stem(data, use_line_collection=True)
axs[1].bar(range(len(data)), np.ones_like(data), width=1, color='white', ec='black')
axs[1].bar(range(len(data)), data, width=1, color='orange', ec='black')

axs[2].pcolormesh(np.arange(-0.5, len(data)), [0, 1], data.reshape(1, -1), cmap=ListedColormap(['white', 'orange']),
                  ec='black')
for ax in axs:
    ax.set_ylim(0, 2)
    ax.set_xticks(range(len(data)))
for ax in axs[1:]:
    ax.set_yticks([])
    for dir in ['left', 'right', 'bottom', 'top']:
        ax.spines[dir].set_visible(False)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: resulting plot]

To answer your new question, with 200 points between 0 and 1:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap
import numpy as np

data = np.random.randint(0, 2, 200)
x_data = np.linspace(0, 1, data.size + 1)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(14, 1))
ax.pcolormesh(x_data, [0, 1], data.reshape(1, -1), cmap=ListedColormap(['white', 'orange']), ec='black', lw=0.5)
ax.set_ylim(0, 1.5)
ax.set_xticks(x_data[::10])
ax.set_yticks([])
for dir in ['left', 'right', 'bottom', 'top']:
    ax.spines[dir].set_visible(False)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: 200 points]

Comment: Does the first or the second part of the answer solve your problem?